# How to add extra css class to comment-reply-link generated by comment_reply_link function ?

Tags: wordpress

So, here is the problem in adding css class in WordPress comment reply section

**comment_reply_link** function adds css class **comment-reply-link** in reply button. Is there as way I can add new css class to **comment-reply-link** ?

I know that I can do that using jquery but is there any way of doing so ***without using jquery*** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this, I add **class** to **comment-reply-link**

```
<?php 
    $myclass = 'icon-share-alt';
    echo preg_replace( '/comment-reply-link/', 'comment-reply-link ' . $myclass, 
        get_comment_reply_link(array_merge( $args, array(
            'add_below' => $add_below, 
            'depth' => $depth, 
            'max_depth' => $args['max_depth']))), 1 ); 
?>
```

**Screenshot**:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Combining a couple of the other answers

```
function custom_comment_reply_link($content) {
    $extra_classes = 'button button--small button--white';
    return preg_replace( '/comment-reply-link/', 'comment-reply-link ' . $extra_classes, $content);
}

add_filter('comment_reply_link', 'custom_comment_reply_link', 99);
```

This adds the value of `$extra_classes` to all reply links 'class' attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a filter to the `comment_reply_link` function.

```
function comment_reply_link_filter($content){
    return '<div class="yourclass">' . $content . '</div>';
}
add_filter('comment_reply_link', 'comment_reply_link_filter', 99);
```

I know it's not directly on the element, but you can now style the element with `.yourclass > .comment-reply-link`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Actually, I want to integrate Bootstrap buttons into WordPress comment  reply section. So, I don't think above solution would be a good choice. If you know any other way, then it will be appreciated.

Thank you again !

Comment: Can you post what you get if you replace `return '<div class="yourclass">' . $content . '</div>';` for `return var_dump($content);`? Maybe you can parse the output and try to add your class.

Comment: After using your first code I got this error.

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare comment_reply_link_filter() (previously declared in E:\zampp\htdocs\wp\wp-content\themes\_raw\inc\template-tags.php:115) in E:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-content\themes\_raw\inc\template-tags.php on line 115

Comment: After replacing second line with return var_dump($content); another error shows up

string(162) "Reply" 
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare comment_reply_link_filter_test() (previously declared in E:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-content\themes\_raw\inc\template-tags.php:115) in E:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-content\themes\_raw\inc\template-tags.php on line 115

Comment: Do you still get the error if you replace `comment_reply_link_filter` by `addclass_comment_reply_link_filter`? Be sure to replace the name in the add_filter function too.